# Unable to click on submenu which is appeared from mousehover

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I have tried below ways but no luck

Attempt 1 :

```
WebElement profile =  dr.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='wp-admin-bar-top-secondary']//a[@title='My Account']"));
WebElement logout = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='wp-admin-bar-user-actions']/li["+i+"]/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(dr);
action.moveToElement(profile).perform();
action.moveToElement(logout).click().perform();
```

Attempt 2 :

```
Actions action = new Actions(dr);
action.moveToElement(profile).click(logout).perform();
```

Attempt 3 :

```
Actions action = new Actions(dr);
action.moveToElement(profile).perform();

List<WebElement> l = dr.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wp-admin-bar-user-actions']/li"));
for(int i=0;i<=l.size()-1;i++){
    WebElement s = l.get(i);
    System.out.println(l.get(i).getText());
    if(s.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("logout")){
        //  WebElement logout = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='wp-admin-bar-user-actions']/li["+i+"]/a"));
            action.moveToElement(dr.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='wp-admin-bar-user-actions']/li["+i+"]/a"))).click().build().perform();
            //s.click();
        }
    }
```

Please help me on this, what could be the issue.

Comment: Does profile open by `mouseover` or `click`?

Comment: Profile element for Mouseover